# How to manage the same frame like 2 different objects importing it from same file

Tags: python, wxpython

I have ManageFrame.py that is very big so I'm trying to reduce it, saving its part like an external files and importing them.

I'm stuck trying to import the same frame like 2 different object.

I made a simple example of ManageFrame.py that wish to import 2 identical FrameDisplay.py
but they are like unique object, when I change range_val (or any other var) in ones it change also in the other frame.

Which is my mistake?

ManageFrame.py

```
import FrameDisplay
f_1 = FrameDisplay.Start_frame()
f_2 = FrameDisplay.Start_frame()


def OnFrame_white():
    v_1 = FrameDisplay.MyFr
    v_1.next_frame = 'Frame_cyan'
    v_1.frame_color = 'WHITE'
    v_1.frameName = 'Range_1'
    f_1.show_frame()
    upper_limit = v_1.upper_limit
    range_val = v_1.range_val
    print('upper_limit', upper_limit)
    print('range_val', range_val)
    exit_val = v_1.exit_val
    next_frame = v_1.next_frame
    return exit_val, next_frame


def OnFrame_cyan():
    v_2 = FrameDisplay.MyFr
    v_2.next_frame = 'Frame_white'
    v_2.frame_color = 'CYAN'
    v_2.frameName = 'Range_2'
    f_2.show_frame()
    upper_limit = v_2.upper_limit
    range_val = v_2.range_val
    print('upper_limit', upper_limit)
    print('range_val', range_val)
    exit_val = v_2.exit_val
    next_frame = v_2.next_frame
    return exit_val, next_frame


def main():

    exit_val = False
    next_frame = 'Frame_white'
    while exit_val is False:
        exit_val = True
        if next_frame == 'Frame_white':
            exit_val, next_frame = OnFrame_white()
            continue
        if next_frame == 'Frame_cyan':
            exit_val, next_frame = OnFrame_cyan()
            continue
    exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('from keyboard')
    loop_main = main()

else:
    print('as sub')
    loop_main = main()
```

FrameDisplay.py

```
import wx.adv


class MyFr(wx.Frame):
    x_p, y_p = -1, -1
    w_a, h_a = -1, -1
    upper_limit, range_val = 1, 1
    frameName = __name__
    frame_color = 'WHITE'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyFr, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()
        MyFr.exit_val = False

    def InitUI(self):

        self.CreateWidgets()
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(MyFr.frame_color)

        self.SetTitle(MyFr.frameName)
        if MyFr.x_p == -1:
            self.Centre()
        else:
            self.SetPosition((MyFr.x_p, MyFr.y_p))
            self.SetSize((MyFr.w_a, MyFr.h_a))
        self.Show(True)

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.panel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self)

        txt = f'Open frame {MyFr.next_frame}'
        self.open_next_frame = wx.Button(
            self.panel, size=(-1, -1), label=txt)
        self.open_next_frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenNextFrame)

        self.exit_valBtn = wx.Button(
            self.panel, size=(-1, -1), label='EXIT')
        self.exit_valBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        upperLimit_lbl = wx.StaticText(
            self.panel, label='UPPER LIMIT:', size=(160, -1))
        # upperLimit_lbl.SetForegroundColour(MyFr.frameTxtCol)
        self.upperLimit = wx.TextCtrl(
            self.panel, size=(100, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.upperLimit.SetValue(str(MyFr.upper_limit))
        self.upperLimit.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnUpperLimit)

        range_lbl = wx.StaticText(
            self.panel, label='RANGE:', size=(160, -1))
        self.range_val = wx.TextCtrl(
            self.panel, size=(100, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.range_val.SetValue(str(MyFr.range_val))
        self.range_val.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnRange_val)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(upperLimit_lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        sizer.Add(self.upperLimit, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(range_lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        sizer.Add(self.range_val, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.open_next_frame, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.exit_valBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        self.panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)
        self.panel.Layout()
        w, h = self.panel.GetSize()
        self.panel.SetScrollbars(1, 1, w, h)
        self.panel.SetScrollRate(1, 1)  # Pixels per scroll increment

    def OnUpperLimit(self, event):
        """Set upper limit"""
        field = event.GetEventObject()
        field_val = field.GetValue()
        MyFr.upper_limit = int(field_val)

    def OnRange_val(self, event):
        """Set range"""
        field = event.GetEventObject()
        field_val = field.GetValue()
        MyFr.range_val = int(field_val)

    def Save_Position(self):
        MyFr.x_p, MyFr.y_p = self.GetPosition()
        MyFr.w_a, MyFr.h_a = self.GetSize()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        MyFr.exit_val = True
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()

    def OnOpenNextFrame(self, event):
        # do something
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        MyFr.exit_val = True
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()


class Start_frame():

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def show_frame(self, *args):
        ex = wx.App()
        MyFr(None)
        ex.MainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('from keyboard')
else:
    print('as sub')
```

Thankyou furas, I tried to use () rewriting row 7

```
v_1 = FrameDisplay.MyFr()
```

and row 22

```
v_2 = FrameDisplay.MyFr()
```

but have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/magic21/Documenti/ARRIVI/MyMod/ManageFrame.py", line 53, in <module>
    loop_main = main()
  File "/home/magic21/Documenti/ARRIVI/MyMod/ManageFrame.py", line 43, in main
    exit_val, next_frame = OnFrame_white()
  File "/home/magic21/Documenti/ARRIVI/MyMod/ManageFrame.py", line 7, in OnFrame_white
    v_1 = FrameDisplay.MyFr()
  File "/home/magic21/Documenti/ARRIVI/MyMod/FrameDisplay.py", line 12, in __init__
    super(MyFr, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
wx._core.PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!
```

Also if I use self. instead of MyFr. then how can I reach v_1.range_val like in row 13 "range_val = v_1.range_val"

Last but not least, You say to create only one wx.App() but if I duplicate FrameDisplay.py in a second file FrameDisplay_2.py and import both it's working. But if I need more than 2 doesn't have sense duplicate files, I wish import the same file many times but each one with their own different range_val like different objects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You've swapped your filenames as compared to the code.

Comment: Yes was swapped, now Is correct.

Comment: prorgam should have only one `wx.App()` and one `ex.MainLoop()` but you create two `Start_frame()` which have `show_frame()` with `wx.App()` and `ex.MainLoop()`

Comment: to have unique objects you have to create instances of class - so you have to use `()` in `v_1 = FrameDisplay.MyFr()` and `v_2 = FrameDisplay.MyFr()`

Comment: inside `MyFr` you have to use `self.` instead of `MyFr.` to keep unique values in every instance. Using `MyFr` you share values between objects.

Comment: Thankyou furas, I tried to use () but have this error: (see added edited question)

Also if I use self. instead of MyFr. then how can I reach v_1.range_val like in row 13 "range_val = v_1.range_val"

Last but not least, You say to create only one wx.App() but if I duplicate FrameDisplay.py in a second file FrameDisplay_2.py and import both it's working. But if I need more than 2 doesn't have sense duplicate files, I wish import the same file many times but each one with their own different range_val like different objects

Answer (score 0):

My goal is to have stored in file one "Frame_Model.py", importing it from "Main_Manager.py" and to use it multiple times as many times I need and use they like different objects storing for eachone their own variables some shared and other not shared, without loosing it after self.Destroy().

The reason is because my "Main_Manager.py" is very long and complicated one and I need simplify it saving external modules in external files and also have a lot of frames to import and these frames are used also from others modules

I found only one way to solve:

made a copy of file "Frame_Model.py" as many times as many objects I need chancing only filename "Frame_Model_2.py"; "Frame_Model_3.py" and so on... (This is a litle bit crazy but it's working).

Follow a full working project:

ManageFrame.py  # is main manager module file

FrameArrivi_esempio.py  # is frame model module file

FrameResa_esempio.py  # is frame model module file (identical copy of FrameArrivi_esempio.py)

ManageFrame.py

```
import FrameArrivi_esempio as fr_1
import FrameResa_esempio as fr_2
f_1 = fr_1.Start_frame()
f_2 = fr_2.Start_frame()

def OnFrame_white():
    v_1 = fr_1.MyFr
    v_1.next_frame = 'Frame_cyan'
    v_1.frame_color = 'WHITE'
    v_1.frameName = 'Range_1'
    f_1.show_frame()
    upper_limit = v_1.upper_limit  # not shared var
    range_val = v_1.range_val  # not shared var
    print('upper_limit', upper_limit)
    print('range_val', range_val)
    exit_val = v_1.exit_val  # shared var
    next_frame = v_1.next_frame  # shared var
    return exit_val, next_frame


def OnFrame_cyan():
    v_2 = fr_2.MyFr
    v_2.next_frame = 'Frame_white'
    v_2.frame_color = 'CYAN'
    v_2.frameName = 'Range_2'
    f_2.show_frame()
    upper_limit = v_2.upper_limit  # not shared var
    range_val = v_2.range_val  # not shared var
    print('upper_limit', upper_limit)
    print('range_val', range_val)
    exit_val = v_2.exit_val  # shared var
    next_frame = v_2.next_frame  # shared var
    return exit_val, next_frame


def main():

    exit_val = False
    next_frame = 'Frame_white'
    while exit_val is False:
        exit_val = True
        if next_frame == 'Frame_white':
            exit_val, next_frame = OnFrame_white()
            continue
        if next_frame == 'Frame_cyan':
            exit_val, next_frame = OnFrame_cyan()
            continue
    exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('from keyboard')
    loop_main = main()

else:
    print('as sub')
    loop_main = main()
```

FrameArrivi_esempio.py

```
import wx.adv


class MyFr(wx.Frame):
    x_p, y_p = -1, -1  # not shared var
    w_a, h_a = -1, -1  # not shared var
    upper_limit, range_val = 1, 1  # not shared var
    frameName = __name__
    frame_color = 'WHITE'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyFr, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()
        MyFr.exit_val = False

    def InitUI(self):

        self.CreateWidgets()
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(MyFr.frame_color)

        self.SetTitle(MyFr.frameName)
        if MyFr.x_p == -1:
            self.Centre()
        else:
            self.SetPosition((MyFr.x_p, MyFr.y_p))
            self.SetSize((MyFr.w_a, MyFr.h_a))
        self.Show(True)

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.panel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self)

        txt = f'Open frame {MyFr.next_frame}'
        self.open_next_frame = wx.Button(
            self.panel, size=(-1, -1), label=txt)
        self.open_next_frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenNextFrame)

        self.exit_valBtn = wx.Button(
            self.panel, size=(-1, -1), label='EXIT')
        self.exit_valBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        upperLimit_lbl = wx.StaticText(
            self.panel, label='UPPER LIMIT:', size=(160, -1))
        # upperLimit_lbl.SetForegroundColour(MyFr.frameTxtCol)
        self.upperLimit = wx.TextCtrl(
            self.panel, size=(100, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.upperLimit.SetValue(str(MyFr.upper_limit))
        self.upperLimit.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnUpperLimit)

        range_lbl = wx.StaticText(
            self.panel, label='RANGE:', size=(160, -1))
        self.range_val = wx.TextCtrl(
            self.panel, size=(100, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.range_val.SetValue(str(MyFr.range_val))
        self.range_val.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnRange_val)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(upperLimit_lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        sizer.Add(self.upperLimit, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(range_lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        sizer.Add(self.range_val, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.open_next_frame, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.exit_valBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        self.panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)
        self.panel.Layout()
        w, h = self.panel.GetSize()
        self.panel.SetScrollbars(1, 1, w, h)
        self.panel.SetScrollRate(1, 1)  # Pixels per scroll increment

    def OnUpperLimit(self, event):
        """Set upper limit"""
        field = event.GetEventObject()
        field_val = field.GetValue()
        MyFr.upper_limit = int(field_val)  # not shared var

    def OnRange_val(self, event):
        """Set range"""
        field = event.GetEventObject()
        field_val = field.GetValue()
        MyFr.range_val = int(field_val)  # not shared var

    def Save_Position(self):
        MyFr.x_p, MyFr.y_p = self.GetPosition()  # not shared var
        MyFr.w_a, MyFr.h_a = self.GetSize()  # not shared var

    def OnExit(self, event):
        MyFr.exit_val = True
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()

    def OnOpenNextFrame(self, event):
        # do something
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        MyFr.exit_val = True
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()


class Start_frame():

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def show_frame(self, *args):
        ex = wx.App()
        MyFr(None)
        ex.MainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('from keyboard')
else:
    print('as sub')
```

FrameResa_esempio.py

```
import wx.adv


class MyFr(wx.Frame):
    x_p, y_p = -1, -1  # not shared var
    w_a, h_a = -1, -1  # not shared var
    upper_limit, range_val = 1, 1  # not shared var
    frameName = __name__
    frame_color = 'WHITE'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyFr, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()
        MyFr.exit_val = False

    def InitUI(self):

        self.CreateWidgets()
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(MyFr.frame_color)

        self.SetTitle(MyFr.frameName)
        if MyFr.x_p == -1:
            self.Centre()
        else:
            self.SetPosition((MyFr.x_p, MyFr.y_p))
            self.SetSize((MyFr.w_a, MyFr.h_a))
        self.Show(True)

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.panel = wx.ScrolledWindow(self)

        txt = f'Open frame {MyFr.next_frame}'
        self.open_next_frame = wx.Button(
            self.panel, size=(-1, -1), label=txt)
        self.open_next_frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenNextFrame)

        self.exit_valBtn = wx.Button(
            self.panel, size=(-1, -1), label='EXIT')
        self.exit_valBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        upperLimit_lbl = wx.StaticText(
            self.panel, label='UPPER LIMIT:', size=(160, -1))
        # upperLimit_lbl.SetForegroundColour(MyFr.frameTxtCol)
        self.upperLimit = wx.TextCtrl(
            self.panel, size=(100, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.upperLimit.SetValue(str(MyFr.upper_limit))
        self.upperLimit.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnUpperLimit)

        range_lbl = wx.StaticText(
            self.panel, label='RANGE:', size=(160, -1))
        self.range_val = wx.TextCtrl(
            self.panel, size=(100, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.range_val.SetValue(str(MyFr.range_val))
        self.range_val.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnRange_val)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(upperLimit_lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        sizer.Add(self.upperLimit, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(range_lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        sizer.Add(self.range_val, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.open_next_frame, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.exit_valBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 1)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

        self.panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)
        self.panel.Layout()
        w, h = self.panel.GetSize()
        self.panel.SetScrollbars(1, 1, w, h)
        self.panel.SetScrollRate(1, 1)  # Pixels per scroll increment

    def OnUpperLimit(self, event):
        """Set upper limit"""
        field = event.GetEventObject()
        field_val = field.GetValue()
        MyFr.upper_limit = int(field_val)  # not shared var

    def OnRange_val(self, event):
        """Set range"""
        field = event.GetEventObject()
        field_val = field.GetValue()
        MyFr.range_val = int(field_val)  # not shared var

    def Save_Position(self):
        MyFr.x_p, MyFr.y_p = self.GetPosition()  # not shared var
        MyFr.w_a, MyFr.h_a = self.GetSize()  # not shared var

    def OnExit(self, event):
        MyFr.exit_val = True
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()

    def OnOpenNextFrame(self, event):
        # do something
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        MyFr.exit_val = True
        self.Save_Position()
        self.Destroy()


class Start_frame():

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def show_frame(self, *args):
        ex = wx.App()
        MyFr(None)
        ex.MainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('from keyboard')
else:
    print('as sub')
```